# Unparseable Date: Multi type Date format coming back in Json

Tags: java, android, json, date, gson

I receive this Date from the API:

```
"DateAdded": "\/Date(1446751484603-0000)\/",
```

I know I can add a type adapter for a long coming back but how would I deal with something that has both String and long elements. I plan to just change this "date" to a Date by hand in my code in the getDate call but I would like to use Gson to format this as a date.

Anyone have some advice on putting some logic into Gson to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you just use ISO 8601?

Comment: I am the client getting the data from the API. In this case I can't tell them how to return the Date, it is just returned that way and I have to work with it.

Comment: Well then it seems like what is between `/Date(...)/` is a Unix timestamp followed by a zone offset; had you used Java per se I could have helped but you seem to be using Android, so...